# Formalization of a simple statement regarding intervals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have the following statement:

***"The open interval (0,1) contains no 'largest' number"***

Which I am asked to "formalize" (I hope I am using the correct mathematical jargon here).

I think the most correct way to formalize it is:

$$\forall a (((a>0) \wedge (a<1)) \rightarrow \exists b ((a<b) \wedge (b<1)))$$

I would like to hear your opinion about it.

But is the following also correct? If not, why?

$$\forall a \exists b((a>0) \wedge (a<1) \wedge (a<b) \wedge (b<1))$$

Comment: It depends on the domain you are quantifying over when you write "for all $a$". For all $a$ where?

Comment: It doesn't specify in the question. The question just gives different formalizations of the statement I have given, and I am asked to mark which ones are correct. @MichalAdamaszek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$\forall a\;(((a>0) \wedge (a<1)) \rightarrow \exists b\;((a<b) \wedge (b<1)))$$ $$\forall a \exists b\:\:((a>0) \wedge (a<1) \wedge (a<b) \wedge (b<1))$$

Let's call the two statements **First** and **Second**. Their domain of discourse is $\mathbb R.$

1. **First** accurately formalises the given verbal statement, and is a true statement.
2. **Second** claims that whatever $a$ is, we can find some $b$ such that $a∈(0,1)$ and $a<b<1;$ the counterexample $a=100$ clearly shows
   that **Second** is a false statement.
3. **First** is logically equivalent to $\forall x \exists y\;(((x>0) \wedge (x<1)) \to ((x<y) \wedge (y<1))).$
   ([Why?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form))
4. **Second** logically implies **First** (why?), but not vice versa (why?); that is, **Second** is a stronger statement than **First**.

Comment: P.S. [This previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4293729/21813) may also be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

If you translate this to human language the first expression says:

- "for all $a$ in $(0,1)$ there exists a $b$ between $a$ and one" (perfect).

The second expression sounds odd:

- "for all $a$ [*which ones?*] there exists a $b$ such that $a$ is in $(0,1)$ and $b$ is between $a$ and one."

It is certainly not true that any $a$ is in $(0,1)$.

Comment: But is it even correct to say "For all a, if a is in (0,1) ...... " because then it's not for all a. It's like saying "For every colour, if it is white ......" . It's not for every colour in that case. It sounds a bit stupid to say.

Comment: You are right. "For all $a$, if a is in $(0,1)$ ... " is another human language version of your *first* logical statement. The second one is bogus.

Comment: **Second** (borrowing the legend in my Answer) *is* syntactically correct and semantically meaningful, and in fact, the form $∀x{\in}(2,3)\;P(x)$ that you're used to is actually an [abbreviation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232992/21813) of $∀x\;\big(x{\in}(2,3){\implies}P(x)\big).$ This statement asserts that $P(2.7)$ is true while making no claim about the truth value of $P(4.5).$ [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4272817/21813) is a longer explanation. @MCFromScratch

Comment: @ryang . Thanks for pointing this out. If I now understand correctly : $\forall x \exists y\;(((x>0) \wedge (x<1)) \color{green}{\to} ((x<y) \wedge (y<1)))$ is a correct version of the first statement and $\forall x \exists y\;(((x>0) \wedge(x<1)) \color{red}{\wedge}  ((x<y) \wedge (y<1)))$ is the wrong second statement. The difference lies in $\color{green}{\to}$ versus $\color{red}{\wedge} $.